# Where I'm doing wrong in checking and adding the new array key with value in a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I've an multi-dimensional array titled `'$result'` as follows :

```
//output of print_r($result);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 333                    
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [group_name] => CHE100
                    [event_id] => 332
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 294                    
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 297
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 296
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 298
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 334
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [group_name] => CHE100
                    [event_id] => 336
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [group_name] => Student Organisation
                    [event_id] => 239
                )

        )

)
```

Now I've to iterate through each element of the above array, check whether the key `['rsvp_id']` is present or not. If it's not present, have to add it and assign a string value 'Yes' to it.

For it I tried below code but it didn't work out for me. Can someone please correct my mistake and make the code workable for me?

```
foreach ($result as $i => $key) { 

          if (is_array($key)) {

            foreach ($key as $index => $event) {
              if (!array_key_exists("rsvp_id", $event)) {

                $result[$i][$key]['rsvp_id'] = 'Yes';      
              } 
            }
          }
        }
```

My Final output array should be as follows :

```
   //expected output of print_r($result);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 333                    
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [group_name] => CHE100
                    [event_id] => 332
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => Yes
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 294                    
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => Yes 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 297
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => Yes
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 296
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => Yes 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 298
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => Yes
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 334
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => Yes
                    [group_name] => CHE100
                    [event_id] => 336
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => Yes
                    [group_name] => Student Organisation
                    [event_id] => 239
                )

        )

)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `$result[$i][$key]['rsvp_id'] = 'Yes';` be `$result[$i][$index]['rsvp_id'] = 'Yes';`?

Comment: @JonStirling:No success with above code. Am I making use or array_key_exists() properly and doing other subsequent operations properly?

Comment: I tried the solution of @JonStirling and it worked... Maybe there's some relevant part of your code you didn't show.

Comment: @user2839497 WFM https://3v4l.org/uAQgA

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
foreach ($test as $i => $key) { 
          if (is_array($key)) {
            foreach ($key as $index => $event) {

              if (!array_key_exists("rsvp_id", $event)) {
                $test[$i][$index]['rsvp_id'] = 'Yes';  // Updated code     
              } 
        }
    }
 }
```